# Java mail API on sending mail where mail body should have the summary of the test report

Tags: java, email

I trying to send the test report to concerned people in my team post execution of the test suite. I am able to do that and the mail is going to them where the test extent report is attached to it. I want the summary of the test report should show on the mail body. Please let me know how to do it. Below is the code in java for java mail api:

```
public static void sendReportsThroughMail(String host,String fromAddress,String[] toAddress,String mailSubject,String mailBody) {
    
    
    //String mailBody=parseHtmlResult(reportSummaryLocation);
    File outPutFile=new File(reportFileLocation);
    ExecutionReport= outPutFile.getPath();
    // Get the session object
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    // compose the message
    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
        for(String mail:toAddress)
        {
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mail));
        }               
        message.setSubject(mailSubject);
        // Create the message part
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(mailBody, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");            
        
        // Create a multipart message
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        
        // Set text message part
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        
        // Add Email body and Report Attachment
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(ExecutionReport);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName("Automation_Execution_Report.html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        
        // Send the complete message parts
        message.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Email sent successfully....");
    } catch (Exception mex) {
        System.out.println("Email Not sent.Please check log trace for more details");
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the reportfile with a FileReader/BufferReader line by line and append it to a StringBuilder. Afterwards set it to the mailBody.

```
StringBuilder reportContent = new StringBuilder();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(outPutFile))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       reportContent.append(line);
       reportContent.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
}
```

Comment: I can add that but how will this code post the report summary on mail body. Can you please explain?

Comment: Oh, i thought your report summary is already in the variable mailBody but isn't shown yet.

Comment: Schuller I want the content of the report which is sent as attachment to go in the mail body so that they can get a summary of it before opening the attachment.

Comment: This variable mailbody only holds a string which is displayed when the report is sent. Instead i want the report content to go in the mail body. Is there a way. Please let me know.

Comment: I changed my answer to hopefully fit to your question

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I tried to create a method for the above logic which will return a string and called this method in the mail body. I get the contents in the mail body how however the format is not a pretty one. Any idea on how get a proper format of this on the mail body?

Comment: Is the content of the report summary html?

Comment: Yes it is in HTML. I tried to read the content of extent report which is in HTML. It didn't come up in a pretty way in the mail body but when i read the emailable report which is also in html, it comes up well in a pretty format exactly the same when we open it. This resolves it. I think we need to do some0-thing extra to read the content of extent report. This resolves the issue. Thanks Benjamin!

Comment: I'm happy that i could help. Please don't forget to mark it as the correct answer then.